# Select item by attribute using simplexml

Tags: php, xml, attributes, simplexml

I want to select only specified warehouse to update stock. I.E. I want only 99, but every item has different number of warehouses so the code below only works in 99 warehouse in in 3 row:

```
$quantity_calc = $this_product->stock[2];
```

Here's sample xml:

```
<product sku="123546" supplier="BOSCH" price="1.71">
<stock warehouse="SAND">2.00</stock>
<stock warehouse="44">2.00</stock>
<stock warehouse="55">4.00</stock>
<stock warehouse="77">2.00</stock>
<stock warehouse="88">2.00</stock>
<stock warehouse="97">2.00</stock>
<stock warehouse="99">2.00</stock>
<stock warehouse="33">2.00</stock>
</product>
```

and print_r($this_product->stock);

```
[@attributes] => Array
        (
            [warehouse] => SAND
        )

    [0] => 2.00
    [1] => 2.00
    [2] => 4.00
    [3] => 2.00
    [4] => 2.00
    [5] => 2.00
    [6] => 2.00
    [7] => 2.00
)
```

Comment: What you really want ? selecting the `stock` element where `warehouse="99"` ?

Comment: Yes, but warehouse "99" is not always in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch a part of an DOM use Xpath expressions. `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` provides access to it:

```
$product = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
var_dump(
  (string)$product->xpath('//stock[@warehouse=99]')[0]
);
```

The DOM extension itself has the DOMXpath class for it:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(//stock[@warehouse=99])')
);
```